# Where can I download openssl-tsget?

Tags: openssl

It is weird that I don't have `openssl-tsget` on my machine.  My OpenSSL version is `Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`. Where can I download `openssl-tsget`?

Answer (score 0):

The `tsget` (Time Stamping HTTP/HTTPS client) command is part of the `openssl` Ubuntu package.  See [this Ubuntu manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/tsget.1ssl.html).

Answer (score 0):

tsget (and the tsget manpage) are included in the `openssl` package.

See for yourself:

```
$ dpkg -L openssl | grep tsget
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/tsget.pl
/usr/share/man/man1/tsget.1ssl.gz
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/tsget
```